# To center a leaflet map on a marker from a link or button

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I need to be able to center the leaflet map on a marker when the appropriate button is click.

```
<button onclick='getLoc(" + geojson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0] + "," +     geojson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1] + ")'>View</button>



function getLoc(c){
var c = L.GeoJSON([lng,lat]);
}
```

I'm stuck from here, any help to finish this would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone else has a different way of doing it using JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem

Here is the solution

```
<button onclick='getLoc(" + geojson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0] + "," +     geojson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1] + ")'>View</button>


function getLoc(lat, lng){
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), 12);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for is the [`setView`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview) method.  Assuming that your map variable is called `map`, you can set the lat/lng of the map by calling the method like this:

```
map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13); // ([lat, lng], zoom)
```

Comment: Yea, thats pre-defining the lat and lng, what I need to do is grab individual latitude and longitudes from getLoc(c) every time a button is clicked

Comment: Neotexx, it's hard to know exactly how you plan to pull the lat/lng from the marker, can you provide a jsfiddle?  Assuming you have coordinates, just drop `map.setView([markerLat, markerLng], someZoom)` into the function.

Comment: I'm not trying to pull it from the marker, I'm trying to get the Long and Lat from GeoJSON data which is passed on the onclick to the function. The markers 

I would put it in to JSFiddle, but I'm having problems getting it to work(The map isn't displaying), other than the function I'm having problems with it works in other browsers!

Comment: Without posting your code to a jsfiddle, I can't really help you out.  Even if the code is broken, it will give me an idea of how it is broken.  It looks like part of the problem might be the way you're trying to get the geojson coordinates in the html button element, especially if that code is not inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: No worries, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/A26dn/4/ knowing me, ive missed something important :)

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here.  Here's an updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZAa8T/ with jquery added.  I also added a proper leaflet.js because the one you were using didn't sync up with current leaflet API documentation.  Calling init and other functions was not really working in your fiddle.  Sorry I can't help more, but there's just too much going on here.